# How to create indented lists in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to write a list like that :

```
Lorem : - ipsum  
        - dolor  
        - sit  
        - amet
```

and I didn't find another way than formatting it manually, with "-" and spaces.
The list tool is very practical, but I didn't find a way to create a list at the end of a line.
Maybe you have a tip to do this, I find it very important to structure notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the text side by side with tables (*Table -> Insert Table*) or frames (*Insert -> Frame -> Frame*; anchor *As Character*).

Frames may be somewhat harder to learn, but unlike tables, they adjust automatically.

[image: tables and frames]

The boundaries can be hidden with *View -> Table Boundaries* and *View -> Text Boundaries.*

[image: without boundaries]

Answer (score 0):

If `Lorem` is the present line, hit enter after that. Type `ipsum`, select the line and select bullets to be on. Now press `TAB` and see the magic of List getting indented and going into the sub level. Something like this.

Lorem

- ipsum
- dolor
- sit

Use `SHIFT+TAB` to come back to the previous list level.

Comment: If it would possible that `Lorem` isn't the part of a list, it would answer more precisely

Comment: Not exactly, I will use that if it's not possible to do it like I wanted, but I wonder if it is possible in this software..

Comment: It seems not possible to put `ipsum` on the same line, and it's not so annoying, so thanks a lot.  Still, if a LibreOffice dev come by here, please implement this !

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for enhancements.  Instead, you can [file a bug](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/81876/where-to-place-an-enhancement-request/).  However, this does not look like a useful feature to me, because there are already solutions such as in my answer.